# Non-std C++ exception React Native Expo w/Nativewind

Tags: react-native, expo, nativewind

I am attempting to install my project from `github` onto several new devices so that my team may program along with me. The project runs just fine on the original device. Every device we have attempted this on as received the following error.

```
non-std C++ exception

ABI49_0_0RCTFatal
ABI49_0_0RCTConvertArrayValue
89420547-98A3-352A-AD2B-BBCB6006FB29
89420547-98A3-352A-AD2B-BBCB6006FB29
89420547-98A3-352A-AD2B-BBCB6006FB29
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
B37A1273-B0C2-312E-9E0B-7143FB645C69
B37A1273-B0C2-312E-9E0B-7143FB645C69
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
F1A8BD61-9CF2-3054-B622-CB63D6CEB4CB
UIApplicationMain
main
A795AD37-6266-385E-95E6-C1CA804C926E
```

Here is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "yum",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "expo": "^49.0.21",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-navigation": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have made the repository public so that others may pull it and attempt the install themselves.

> github.com/JacobJJoness/Yum

I have already run `npm install` on every device. Along with ensuring `node.js` is up to date, and are using the local expo cli within our node modules. I have also ensured that tailwind is update. I have attempted the solutions from the following threads to no avail.
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76375461/how-can-i-solve-a-non-std-c-exception-in-my-react-native-typescript-applicatio)

I have been dealing with this error for two weeks. If anyone has any suggestions or needs more information please let me know I will be keeping a sharp eye on this thread.